# Add multiple conditional CSS classes in HTML with Rails string interpolation

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using Rails and trying to conditionally add a div height based on a query string param. There are four possible values for the `v` query string param: 1, 2, 3, or 4. When `v=3` or `v=4`, I want to display the `heading-row-2` class. Otherwise, I want to display the `heading-row` class.

I'm looking for something along the lines of these two:

```
<%= content_tag :div, class: "row #{'heading-row-2' ? (params[:v] == 3 || 4) : 'heading-row'}"%>

<div class="row <%='heading-row-2' ? (params[:v] == 3 || 4) : 'heading-row'%> ">
```

Note that I also need:
- A 'row' tag.
- To add more html *inside* the div.

Comment: A better alternative to  string interpolation in complex cases may be  to create an array of classes and just join the array with spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `heading-row` in any case. In case the parameter `v` is 3 or 4 you interpolate the value `-2` to the class option:

```
<%= content_tag :div, class: "row heading-row#{'-2' if params[:v].in?(['3', '4'])}" %>

<div class="row heading-row<%= '-2' if params[:v].in?(['3', '4']) %>">
```

The second way seems easier to read.

---

Notice

```
params[:v] == 3 || 4
```

Might not be what you expect, as it means "if the value of params[:v] is equal to 3 then return true otherwise return 4".

Comment: Awesome. I like how concise it is. However, I'm getting the following error: `no implicit conversion of Array into String`. I'm using the second option you provided. Not sure if this matters, but this is what is in `Parameters`: `{"v"=>"3"}`.

Comment: Sorry, I mixed the order there. It should be `params[:v].in?(['3', '4'])`, can you try again?

Comment: That did it. Thank you!